# Edit ”view” in google bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I’m new to bigquery and SQL and struggling with something. Once I’ve created a view with a certain name, ex

```
CREATE VIEW ‘database.table1’ AS
SELECT 1=1
```

I can’t seem to figure out how to edit that view. How can I substitute all contents in table1 to a completely other table without deleting the view, and creating another view with the same name again?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to alter the SQL statement generates data for the view you can run a CREATE OR REPLACE statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ‘database.table1’ AS
SELECT 2
```

It is important to note that views do not actually contain data, they just execute the given sql command.  If you need to modify the data in an underlying table the view points to you will need to run a DML statement.
Documentation can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_view_statement

Answer (score 1):

**Other way around is,**

Click on already created view,
Go to Details tab and click on "edit query".
View definition will be open in editor.
Make necessary changes then click on "Save View".
A pop will come to overwrite existing view. Say ok and you are all set.

**Refer below screenshot for each option.**

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, you want to "dump" all the data in table1 into another table?

That can be done with

```
insert into table2 (column1, column2, etc) 
select column1, column2, etc from table1
```

Then you would just delete table1 because it's just a view and recreate it.